# Bivariate probit model with sample selection

Tags: econometrics, bias, bivariate

Could you please provide an example and explanation why to use the bivariate probit model with sample selection?

In this context, to what sample selection bias refers to?

Comment: Do you mean a recursive bivariate probit, where one binary outcome appears as a regressor in the other binary outcome equation?

Comment: I don't know if it is called like that, but it involves selection and outcome equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I lost the tex file for these notes, but they are only two pages, so I added screenshots:

[image]
[image]

I have [a paper](http://research.ebay.com/sites/default/files/sniping_www_final1.pdf) where we use this approach to look at what happens to bidders who lose to a sniper in their very first auction on eBay. A sniper is another participant who tries to place a bid in the final seconds of sequential ascending auctions with predetermined ending times. The outcome $y_1$ is binary: leaving the auction platform or not. The sniped dummy $y_2$ is in the outcome equation of $y_1$.

The reason you can't just put $y_2$ as a regressor is that sniping is more likely to occur in markets where there are few bidders. It is these kind of markets for which a marketplace like eBay is most attractive to buyers, implying that bidders in these markets may be more likely to return to eBay. Hence, a positive correlation between sniping and auction thinness, and a positive correlation between auction thinness and the likelihood of returning to eBay, will bias downward any effect that sniping has on bidders ceasing to bid in auctions. That is, there is selection into which auctions gets sniped.

We use a recursive bivariate probit strategy to address this concern. There are two ways that bidding occurs on eBay. First, bidders can manually insert their bid into the proxy bidding system. Second, bidders can use sniping software that does this automatically in the last seconds of the
auction without their attentiveness. At nighttime, there are fewer manual bidders active on the site, and consistent with this we observe that more auctions are won by snipers. However, 10pm in New York is only 7pm in San Francisco, while 10pm in San Francisco is 1am in New York. Therefore the
10pm San Francisco bidder is much more likely to be sniped than a 10pm New York bidder. If these bidders are otherwise comparable conditional on observables, then one can use their respective time zones as an instrument for variation in the likelihood of being sniped. This is the basis of
our identification strategy.

---

**Reference:**

Matt Backus, Tom Blake, Dimitriy V Masterov, and Steven Tadelis, "Is Sniping A Problem For Online Auction Markets?",    *Proceedings of the 24th International Conference on World Wide Web*, 88-96.

---

**Response to Question:**

Here's a *toy* example illustrating the fundamental problem with selection, setting aside the bivariate probit stuff. The 250 circles below correspond to people with different levels of education and their *potential* wage offers. Suppose anyone who gets a wage offer of \$15 or less decides that he would rather go hiking instead of working, so we don't get to see his wage (orange circles). If you fit a linear model to the remaining data (navy circles), the slope will be 20% smaller than on the full sample, so the benefit of going to school will appear $0.50 lower than it really is. One way to think about this is the people with large negative epsilons are more likely to be missing in the low education groups, so it inflates the observed wages in those groups, which tilts the regression line and makes schooling look less effective.

Why does this matter? Let's focus on the fifth highest orange circle with 11 years of education, who may be right on the margin between dropping out of high school (we don't observe his costs here). His offer with 11 years of education is just under \$13. If he thinks the benefit of another year is \$2, he may leave school because he can just start hiking now and not incur the unnecessary cost. Since economists are interested in policy questions (like what would be the net benefit of college loan forgiveness), ignoring the people who went hiking (or aren't in the labor force) would be a poor choice. Using the wrong estimate could lead to some suboptimal investment in education, both individually and socially.

If your goal is to predict what the wage among workers with X years of education is, using the worker data would be OK. It is when you want to make causal statements about what would have happened to someone had they completed more school that you need to worry about selection. [image]

---

Data:

```
x   y
10  36.77875
13  29.92348
12  17.84871
10  21.6781
12  10.68797
8   29.45379
12  12.50187
9   22.7946
11  20.16943
12  34.30902
11  34.29064
13  15.70758
12  11.20882
12  33.84629
10  29.01311
14  22.38047
12  54.72863
11  49.56858
15  24.02602
13  36.42536
12  22.71795
10  19.54785
14  38.4038
14  34.30227
10  19.37613
11  2.086503
14  26.4395
9   14.80535
14  26.08193
11  30.91514
13  32.0592
8   34.08197
12  28.76042
13  38.68304
13  47.95863
11  24.46299
14  30.65527
16  54.57944
10  13.10431
14  25.30962
9   32.48787
11  24.64828
12  25.96807
11  16.65392
12  36.22239
14  25.20041
12  17.36436
12  38.27636
11  24.94589
10  31.49921
13  25.5742
12  25.78094
15  45.46352
11  21.08684
13  12.91339
11  33.41261
14  25.76663
14  49.73616
11  22.67634
16  55.26606
12  33.48164
15  33.87222
11  16.43427
10  21.37041
13  29.18699
9   20.20561
10  44.55228
13  47.68126
11  27.97073
12  36.06765
12  35.84951
11  11.26081
15  36.36755
16  23.63187
13  41.6813
12  30.994
13  31.27638
15  38.53747
11  48.27272
12  25.59191
16  44.45938
14  45.71571
14  33.68782
10  33.39376
12  45.53596
13  27.69209
12  26.27091
11  33.25354
11  16.89751
13  29.82576
11  38.67755
12  37.91254
12  32.57379
15  44.98801
8   13.68349
14  37.57533
13  15.75075
13  26.164
11  22.16672
10  30.29593
13  28.82244
17  43.92926
10  3.793436
14  54.33921
11  30.367
15  33.27439
15  11.65642
11  24.98503
11  35.55489
12  12.33667
9   19.50787
9   29.07384
13  39.28975
10  18.6426
13  32.62035
11  39.59964
12  38.74402
13  29.84206
11  28.70477
15  27.76243
12  35.0229
9   10.48161
13  32.94176
13  32.26461
13  20.64163
12  28.0451
11  30.72115
12  36.0846
16  52.26955
14  49.25191
15  48.60603
11  43.55553
14  45.27725
8   21.87545
12  27.19747
14  26.53179
9   18.49253
11  8.361289
12  30.11271
14  34.79089
11  39.50394
11  28.82289
12  29.17985
14  29.04272
12  39.28788
16  49.37336
14  44.76436
13  26.92885
11  39.19863
10  26.79517
14  30.74782
15  36.4241
13  27.07322
8   6.324262
10  29.13576
12  20.5755
10  5.107344
13  29.96143
12  30.87452
11  39.13571
12  31.89077
9   10.86587
9   32.571
13  36.32444
12  22.86062
13  31.54544
14  28.71825
12  35.49273
12  18.8854
8   32.67909
13  46.02027
10  35.3645
10  38.09469
11  21.16621
13  37.33644
14  43.37357
11  16.6026
13  36.44201
13  31.3522
11  35.2338
11  26.09209
14  52.26656
10  30.28688
12  36.23479
10  20.65876
11  42.26967
12  33.70919
14  34.77951
12  22.55819
18  54.19498
10  30.39797
15  33.097
11  27.93202
15  32.32858
14  37.80832
15  53.04989
13  35.48972
12  36.6966
11  36.46019
16  39.18628
14  39.73043
12  29.34012
11  24.64899
10  29.82037
11  29.40948
15  27.87559
10  34.42297
12  46.14198
9   23.11894
13  32.52744
16  43.73385
12  61.2392
10  26.99522
13  31.45339
14  36.8537
10  26.05906
15  40.28445
10  31.6895
14  33.68509
11  28.2475
12  10.36757
11  39.6512
11  41.26844
9   16.99724
12  29.98223
13  41.83167
10  23.86976
11  17.47382
12  41.34653
11  21.89777
12  14.88964
10  8.632276
11  13.11433
11  1.543627
15  48.46469
14  25.4514
16  55.7856
10  30.88486
16  23.78511
14  46.50201
12  29.67507
14  31.63361
9   44.99561
10  36.27057
13  32.96661
13  14.41626
13  46.88454
15  40.52191
16  39.17714
12  33.70162
```

Comment: For the sake of the example let's assume we are estimating the effect of age and education on wage. So we are observing only people who actually work and, therefore, have wage. Then we need to estimate selection and outcome equation, respectively. But why do we need to expand our estimate to whole population, i.e. to other non-working part? How are they gonna affect our estimates if they are not working?

Comment: This is not a great example, since both your outcome and endogenous variable are continuous, not binary. The bivariate probit will be an inappropriate model in this case. Employment and college graduate would be better.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that.  However, could you please help me understand why it is necessary to include the whole population and not only deriving conclusions based on the sample of people given certain criteria.

Comment: @quirik Does this makes more sense now?

Comment: Yes, it makes more sense now. Thank you for your effort. In addition, could you please explain what do you mean by "people with large negative epsilons are more likely to be missing in the low education groups, so it inflates the observed wages in those groups.". I guess that the epsilon is the error term so if it's negative, the predicted wage will be larger than observed wage but I'm confused with other part of the sentence.

Comment: It means that people who receive lower wage offers for reasons that are unobservable to us are more likely to be hiking when they have less education. Note that there are a lot fewer orange circles on the right. This rotates the regression line up and biases downward the estimated wage-school profile.

Comment: OK, so you are saying that people with lower education will have larger epsilons due to some unobserved factors (e.g. intelligence)  other than the number of grades completed that affect the wage offer? As a result, we included only the people with hourly wage > $15 and get downward biased results. Does this also mean that we would get negative coefficient of inverse Mill's ratio which we can interpretate that there are unobserved characteristics (intelligence) which increase the probability of selection into the labour market and increase the probability of downward bias on the wage?

Comment: In addition to my previous question, could you please explain what do you mean by "It is when you want to make causal statements about what would have happened to someone had they completed more school that you need to worry about selection." ? Does this mean knowing what wage offer would hiker with 11 years of education and $13 wage would have if he completed more years of education?

Comment: Everyone has the same kind of epsilons here, regardless of their education: there's no heteroskedasticity in the data. I am saying the people with low education and negative epsilons are more likely to be below the 15 threshold and go hiking, so we do not observe their wage. The sign on the IMR indicates the correlation between the unobserved components in the selection and outcome equations, which in this case should be positive. Your understanding of the causal statements sentence is correct.

Comment: How they will have negative epsilons when they are not observed? What am I missing here?

Comment: It's a potential outcome. Think of it as a wage offer, rather than an actual wage. Just because someone did not accept it, doesn't mean it does not exist.

Comment: So we are performing regression among those who work and those who could potentially work for some wage under $15 to obtain unbiased effect of education on wage. As a result, we cannot observe those who don't work so in order to straighten the biased regression line we need to control for some unobserved factors which are related to education and affect the propensity to participate on labour market and level of wage offer, as well. Is this correct?

Comment: This is turning into its own question! It is much better to ask related questions as separate, new questions. You are right that this is essentially an omitted variables problem. If we observed those factors or had an estimate of them, we could fix this by putting them in. From properties of the bivariate normal distribution, we do have such an estimate, up to an unknown parameter: it is the inverse Mills ratio times the its coefficient in the wage equation. This captures the fact that the wage epsilon no longer zero in expectation since the negative epsilons with low education are hiking.

Comment: @Dimitiy V. Masterov Additionally, how can we interpret IMR? What do we get from the ratio of probability density and cummulative distribution function?

Comment: @quirik The IMR times its coefficient is the expected error term for those working.

Comment: In this context, does this mean by how much the wages are shifted up due to selection effect? In other words, it says how much working people with sample average characteristics who are selected in our sample makes % higher hourly wage than someone with equal average chatacteristics but drawn at random?

Comment: Almost right. The percentage part depends on how how wages are measured or transformed, say with logs. The sample average part is wrong. The IMR is a nonlinear function of variables in the selection equation, so you could evaluate it any values, not just the average ones.

Comment: Yes, it occured to me later that percentage are related with log transformation of wage variable. Regarding other part, if I take average of all IMR values, and then multiply it by the coefficient, would my statement be correct?

Comment: Yup. That a great way of doing it's

Comment: @Dimtriy V. Masterova One more doubt: during selection stage, when we calculate the ratio of pdf and cdf, and get e.g. 1.2 and 2.4 for two observations, does this mean that the later has twice as chance/likelihood to be employed if he obtains more years of education?

Comment: It the meantime I have been doing additional reading and come up with another interpretation: person with pdf/cdf = 2.4 is twice as likely to be selected into the sample of workers and not hikers than person with pdf/cdf = 1.2? This is based on the fact that Heckman models selection  and that pdf/cdf is basically a selection hazard rate or the "risk/chance" to be selected for the sample? Please correct me @Dimitriy V. Masterov

Comment: @quirik I have never seen this interpretation and it does not make sense to me. I would looks at the predicted probabilities from the first stage if I wanted to compare.

Comment: How would you interprete the pdf/cdf ratio?

Comment: @quirik I wouldn't, other than in the way I mentioned above. I think this discussion has strayed too far from the original question. I encourage you to start a new question rather than continuing with more here.

Comment: The only mention of something like this that I can find is a very vague statement on p. 183 of Propensity Score Analysis by Guo and Fraser: "In the early days of discussing the Heckman or Heckit models, some researchers, especially economists, assumed that λ [IMR] could be used to measure the level of selectivity effect, but this idea proved controversial and is no longer widely practiced." I still don't get the intuition why someone would do this.

Comment: I found something similiar, as well at: http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic255091.files/Class08.pdf (p. 5)

Comment: Are these statements correct: the distribution of navy circles - potential wage offer given years of education is truncated from the left. As a result the OLS is biased because the predicted value is not at the mean of the distribution - the actual mean of the truncated distribution is higher. Therefore, the Heckman method corrects the mean with the coefficient of the IMR so the regression line could pass as close as possible to the new mean of truncated distribution for navy circles. Pdf/cdf ratio or IMR re-normalizes the truncated distribution so the integral underneath equals 1, as well.

Comment: This method corrects the expected value (or conditional mean) with the coefficient times the IMR (not just the coefficient). The corrected fit should pass through the conditional mean of the blue and the orange (not just the blue). I am not sure what "renormalized" sentence means. Typically, normalization involves some sort of division.

Comment: So it can be said that if sample is selected, and we don't appy Heckman method, the predicted wage doesn't correspond anymore to the conditional mean of blue and orange, just the blue? Therefore, we are adding the sample selection component to the regression or value indicating how far conditional mean of truncated distribution is from the mean of original (untruncated) distribution (blue and orange). As a result, we can se how this affects the true value of wage offer with the help of coefficient of IMR.

Comment: Yes. There are other methods that accomplish this as well.

Comment: How would graph look like for a truncated sample if depentent variable in main equation was binary as well? How truncated sample affects estimating logistic regression?

Comment: @quirik You would have too few zeroes or ones, so it's effectively the same.

Comment: Let say we observe whether children have mobile phone if their parents voted for Obama. What would be the effects of truncated sample on logit regression? Does this mean that the CDF curve would bi biased and from which side the sample would be truncated?

Comment: Heckman selection model assumes that 1) errors of both selection and main equation are correlated and distributed normally, 2) explanatory variables in selection equation are independent of the error term, 3) explanatory variables in main equation are independent of the error term.

Doubt: how can explanatory variables of both equations be independent of error terms, and at the same time, the errors terms be correlated? Or this is the end result only after we included some unobserved factors that affect both selection and main equation?

Comment: Could you please provide the data set from the employment sample selection example?

Comment: @quirik Edited the post with the data.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Additionally, could you provide an example where correlation between unobservables of selection and outcome equation could be negative?

Comment: @quirik I think we have let this question ramble on long enough. We are way off topic from the bivariate probit. Please start another question, with a link to this one.

Comment: I did: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231374/heckman-selection-model-and-negative-rho