# Heckman selection model and negative rho

Tags: self-study, econometrics, heckman

Following this post [Bivariate probit model with sample selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207804/bivariate-probit-model-with-sample-selection), what would be an example of negative correlation between errors of selection and outcome equation?

I have also found an example where rho is negative: http://personal.rhul.ac.uk/uhte/006/ec5040/selectivity.pdf. Based on this example, unobserved factors or positive errors that make participation more likely (e.g. ability) tend to be associated with lower wages or negative errors of outcome equation. What could unobservables in outcome equation represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a toy example with negative correlation in the errors in the two equations.

Let the outcome $y=\alpha + \beta \cdot x + \varepsilon$ represent immigrant earnings, where $x$ is years of schooling. The participation equation $p=\gamma + \delta \cdot x + u$ is the decision to emigrate. We only observe $y$ if $p \ge 0$. There's an unobserved non-cognitive trait called restlessness that makes emigration more likely, we will represent by $u$. But restlessness can also lower wages, so it is part of the error in the earnings equation, but it enters it negatively, so $u$ and $\varepsilon$ are negatively correlated.

Let's suppose that $\delta>0$, so education makes people more likely to leave their home. Folks with low $x$ will only emigrate if they have a high $u$, but people with high $x$ will emigrate with almost any value of $u$. This means that the estimate of the effect of schooling on immigrant income will be too steep since the low education immigrants in our earnings data will be overwhelmingly more restless.

Comment: Is there no truncation point in this example?

Comment: @quirik The wage distribution is still truncated, since you do not observe a wage for those who do not emigrate.

Comment: @quirik Did this help?

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply, I was away. Yes, it helped a lot. Somehow it never occured to me that positive errors in selection equation could enter as positive in outcome equation. Yes, the sample is truncated from below since we only observe people with positive $p$ values.

Comment: When we say the sample is truncated, are we reffering to latent or outcome variable?

Comment: The outcome would be truncated.

Comment: But in this example the earnings could be truncated from below and above, right? And we use the properties of truncated normal distribution from below to calculate $E(\epsilon|p>0)$?

Comment: @quirik I don't think it will be truncated from below. The people with low $u$s and high $\varepsilons$s will be missing, so the truncation will be above for low levels of education and there will be little truncation at high levels.

Comment: But is it possible for outcome variable to be truncated from each side but still estimated with Heckman model since it models selection into the sample for observations with $p>0$?

Comment: @quirik I am not certain it would work straight off-the-shelf.

Comment: For example, aren't those with low education and low wages but they don't emigrate. As with the wage model of working people we would observe $y$ only for a subset of a population that is determined by participation variable. But those who do not work, could still have low and high wages (two sided truncation).  But - if I understand correctly - we need to calculate $E(\epsilon|u)$ and to solve this we use properties of one-sided truncated normal distribution since $u>-\delta x$ regardless of the fact that sample may be truncated from both sides. What am I missing?

Comment: @quirik There is no reason to expect two-sided truncation in this toy model that I can see. Moreover, your original question is about a simple example of correlation between the two errors, not about how to estimate anything. If you have a question about how to estimate a more complicated model, it should be a separate question. It would be more likely to get a better answer since people don't always follow the comments, but may pay attention to new questions. Also, the comments are not the best place for extended discussion of complicated tangential issues.